EMA crossovers with plotting vertical lines
Any idea how to change the style=shape.triangledown to plot vertical line only on chart? I've change to vline, it does not work.
//@version=5
indicator("EMA Crossover", overlay=true)

// Define EMA lengths
ema50 = ta.ema(close, 50)
ema200 = ta.ema(close, 200)

// Detect crossover
ema_crossup = ta.crossover(ema50, ema200)
ema_crossdown = ta.crossunder(ema50, ema200)

// Plot lines on chart when crossover occurs
plotshape(series=ema_crossup, title="EMA Cross Up", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, style=shape.triangleup, size=size.small)
plotshape(series=ema_crossdown, title="EMA Cross Down", location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, style=shape.triangledown, size=size.small)

